# Intent.ACTION does not dial after first # sign

Tags: android

I am trying to make a call with a long number that looks something like this.

tel:883994555,,,32343#,,,#

with code that looks like this.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(number);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

What I see is that, the phone does not dial after the first '#' sigh. Any one knows how to make this to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How I got this to work was to use ';' (semicolon) for the hard wait instead of the 'w', and ',' (comma) for the pause, and then encode the phone number first, like this -

```
Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode(number)))
```

Comment: the # needs to be escaped yes. :) Thanks for the answer. I can not vote up yet due to my low reputation ;)

Comment: ... my reputation permits upvoting though

Answer (score 2):

`Uri.parse(String)` parses an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI.

RFC 2396 says:

> The character "#" is excluded because
>   it is used to delimit a URI from a
>   fragment identifier in URI references.

Comment: So do I have escape that explicitly ?

Comment: Also, # is a dtmf character, so it need not be escaped, but why is the phone dialer ignoring anything after the # sign?

Comment: This is syntax of uri: `[scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]` after "#" is [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)