# Android phone call including comma and hash #

Tags: android, hash, tel

I need to make automatic phone call app with this two character (comma and hash).

I try with this method. If so, all character behind hash is not called.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +"131#3131,,,44"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

So, I try with this method again. Then, all number behind comma is not called. May I know how to do?

```
    Intent out = new Intent();
    out.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+3943#333,,23")));
    startActivity(out);
```

Comment: There's an issue somewhat relating to this on Android issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7993 . Guess it's expected behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: oh...so, it can't be fixed? :O or another way? I can use other similar character or method also. (if there is anything)

Comment: Maybe someone has a workaround - but many times if such exist they are mentioned on bug reports too.

Comment: Thanks. It seen like this app is working. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abzdev.confcalldialerstd
I wonder how they overcome.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer (copied)

```
Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode(number)))
```

Source [Intent.ACTION does not dial after first # sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115887/intent-action-does-not-dial-after-first-sign)