# Intent.ACTION_CALL how to add `,` sign comma

Tags: android, telephonymanager

How to add a `,` comma sign into the phone call intent?
`004216378497,,,,,,,,,2`

my code is now like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: why u need such a functionality?

Comment: you need to put more than one comma?

Comment: @RicardoA. yes sir

Answer (score 1):

Try this way (copied)

```
Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", Uri.encode(number)))
```

Source : [Intent.ACTION does not dial after first # sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115887/intent-action-does-not-dial-after-first-sign)

Comment: unfortunately it does not helped my problem. the comma sign is still ignored by the Android phone :/

Comment: @Csabi, in which device are you checking, because it working fine in oppo device

Comment: @android I have tested it on samsung galaxy s7 edge and pixel 2 for both devices the number is called but everything after the first `,` comma sign is ignored

Comment: @Csabi, i checked it on oppo f7 and it is working. so may be we have to find the solution device wise

Comment: @android yes I have read that it can be android system dependent or maybe device dependent. :/ I really does not know why. I have applied the upper mentioned solution so at least on some devices it will be working